# How to decode and play MPEG-TS stream on Android (188 byte TS packet)

Tags: android, ffmpeg, mpeg2-ts

I am making an application similar to DVB broadcast TV player based on Android. The data I can receive is a series of MPEG-TS packets, each packet may be 188 bytes or 204 bytes. This is not HLS and does not carry There are m3u8 files. May I ask how can I decode these MPEG-TS input streams on Android and play them?

The received data packet is a data packet that conforms to the MPEG-TS encapsulation standard, similar to this
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6rNNO.png)

Comment: 'MPEG-TS' appears to be a supported File Types
Container Format: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/media-formats What have you tried? Have you seen: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/exoplayer

Comment: Although it is written in the document that MPEG-TS is supported, this is only for a whole file, such as a "file" saved in a folder or a "file" that can be directly obtained through the network, which does not meet my needs. My need is to receive To the "packet" after MPEG-TS encoding, it's just a byte array, so I don't think Android's native encoder can meet my needs.
The data I receive is encoded as Wikipedia says: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MPEG_transport_stream

Comment: @Gouzhong1223 Check out the Exoplayer implementation, if I remember correctly it supports MPEG-TS streams over UDP. Or you can just repack your stream to live HLS somewhere in-between.